# "New" is not "active"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I recently (yesterday) [started to really use](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/palos-filter-small-tags-sites) the custom filter feature on stackexchange.com.

Today I remarked that the [*newest* view](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/palos-filter-small-tags-sites?sort=newest) shows some questions (in particular now [The use of cribs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/353/the-use-of-cribs)), which are *not* on the [*activity* view](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/palos-filter-small-tags-sites?sort=active).

This question was created "7 hours ago", which also should count as activity 7 hours ago, I think. The activity view shows questions with activity up to "yesterday" (24 or 25 hours ago, I think), but not this page. **Why?**

This interferes with my goal of using this page as my daily start page, showing me the important changes where I may want to look/vote/answer.

---

Edit: It looks like the default view of the [Questions] tab of the individual sites already works like this, showing both active and new questions. (Although the "active" subtab seems to be the selected tab in the default view, this "active" subtab shows only questions with changes, no new ones. This seems quite strange.)

But this question is about the filtered view on stackexchange.com, where there is no such "both new and active questions" view for the filters. **Please either include the new questions in the active ones, or add a new view showing both new and active ones.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Our service responsible for aggregating question data for consumption by filters wasn't correctly aggregating "activity date" for new questions.

Prior to this fix, questions wouldn't have shown up in filters sorted by activity unless they received a comment, answer, or edit. Fortunately, questions typically receive comments/answers/edits pretty quickly, which is the only reason this bug's effects weren't more severe.

Comment: I can confirm that it works now (i.e. there are questions showing up without comments/answers/...). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw, only questions that have been edited or received new answers appear in the *activity* view. (Also any answer edited, accepted etc..)

This lead me to believe this is "by design" behavior which means that questions won't appear in that view until something happened in them.

By the way, same applies to the [activity view in main SO site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).

Comment: So, I have to edit my new question once for users to see it? I don't think this is a good design.

Comment: The "active" View is not the default, people will see it in the main Questions tab and those who visit just for "active" view should expect to see only questions with changes. The tooltip also says "Questions that have recent activity".

Comment: I think that asking a question is as much activity as editing or answering one. (I only want the new question to be listed between other changes of a similar age.)

Comment: So this is feature request.. but I doubt if many members will agree with you. I'm happy with the current design - to see all questions, just see the Questions tab. :)

Comment: There is no "Questions" tab for the filter view on stackexchange.com. I don't want to see all questions, I just want to see both new and "active" questions (of my selected tags) together.

Comment: Fair enough.. please remove the "bug" tag though. :)

Comment: @Shadow: No, the activity view on the main SO site includes new questions without any answers, edits, comments or upvotes. And I would be _very_ unhappy if this would ever change! That would be a clear bug from my point of view.

Comment: @Shadow: I'll wait until I get word of someone official to decide if this is a bug or "by design".

Comment: @Paulo This is a bug -- we'll deploy a fix tonight.

Comment: Actually, we just deployed (a little sooner than expected), so this is fixed now.